# Payment Gateway plugin for Wordpress site with and without Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I have to make a Payment Gateway plugin for Wordpress based site. I came to know about Woocommerce for Wordpress. I have the following 2 questions:

1) If I make a Payment Gateway plugin for Woocommerce, can it be used on a Wordpress site that does not have Woocommerce?

2) If I make a Payment Gateway plugin for Wordpress, can it be used for Woocommerce as well?

Answer (score 0):

`1) If I make a Payment Gateway plugin for Woocommerce, can it be used on a Wordpress site that does not have Woocommerce?`
No you cannot use Woocommerce Payment Gateway without Woocommerce as the Payment Gateway exctends Payment Gateway Class of Woocommerce. Hope this justify your question.

`2) If I make a Payment Gateway plugin for Wordpress, can it be used for Woocommerce as well?`
It depends on how you code. You need to keep the dependency based on Woocommerce plugin and need to check whether Woocommerce is active or not. To work with Woocommerce you need to extend the core class of Woocommerce.